# Set JVM parameter starting catalina.bat

Tags: java, tomcat, parameters, jvm

In a Windows docker container, I run Tomcat with:

```
> catalina.bat run
```

I can configure Tomcat if it is a Windows Service, for example:

```
"C:\Program Files\Tomcat\bin\tomcat8.exe" //US//Tomcat8 --Jvm="C:\Program Files\Oracle Java Server\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll"
```

But, how can I use that parameter (`--Jvm="path\jvm.dll"`) but running `catalina.bat run` command?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the JAVA_HOME environment variable if you want to specify the JVM to use when running any of the command-line scripts.

You can either do it like this:

```
C:\> SET JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\Java 1.8.0"   [or whatever]
C:\> %CATALINA_HOME%\bin\catalina.bat start
```

Or, you can edit (or create) the file `%CATALINA_BASE\bin\setenv.bat` and add this to it:

```
SET JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\Java 1.8.0"   [or whatever]
```

The script `catalina.bat` will run `setenv.bat – if it exists – before launching the JVM, so you can manually select your own JVM if you prefer.